# Average between points based on time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use Python to get time taken, as well as average speed between an object traveling between points.

The data looks somewhat like this,

```
location    initialtime id  speed distance
    1   2020-09-18T12:03:14.485952Z car_uno 72 9km
    2   2020-09-18T12:10:14.485952Z car_uno 83 8km
    3   2020-09-18T11:59:14.484781Z car_duo 70 9km
    7   2020-09-18T12:00:14.484653Z car_trio    85 8km
    8   2020-09-18T12:12:14.484653Z car_trio    70 7.5km
```

The function I'm using currently is essentially like this,

```
Speeds.index = pd.to_datetime(Speeds.index)
..etc
```

Now if I were doing this usually, I would just take the unique values of the id's,

```
for x in speeds.id.unique():
    Speeds[speeds.id=="x"]...
```

But this method really isn't working.

What is the best approach for simply seeing if there are multiple id points over time, then taking the average of the speeds by that time given? Otherwise just returning the speed itself if there are not multiple values.

Is there a simpler pandas filter I could use?

Expected output is simply,

```
area - id - initial time - journey time - average speed.
```

the point is to get the average time and journey time for a vehicle going past two points

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data? Or need `df.groupby('id').mean()` ?

Comment: @jezrael that groupby is a good idea lol! the only thing is, it needs to take into account the time - i wonder if i can just make a function for that somehow hmm

Comment: @LeCoda I don't really understand what do you mean by average speed, is it the average of the speeds of a car at different areas and at different times? What does such average stand for?

Comment: if the car has been at two spots, then the average speed, given the time taken between spots, and the speed at each spot

Comment: Whats the difference between Speeds and speeds? It seems that you are treating them as the same thing in your for loop..

Comment: do you want to *weight* the average by the timedelta between consecutive entries for a given ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the average speed and journey times you can use `groupby()` and pass in the columns that determine one complete journey, like `id` or `area`.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
area    initialtime id  speed
    1   2020-09-18T12:03:14.485952Z car_uno 72
    2   2020-09-18T12:10:14.485952Z car_uno 83
    3   2020-09-18T11:59:14.484781Z car_duo 70
    7   2020-09-18T12:00:14.484653Z car_trio    85
    8   2020-09-18T12:12:14.484653Z car_trio    70
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

df["initialtime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["initialtime"])

# change to ["id", "area"] if need more granular aggregation
group_cols = ["id"]

time = df.groupby(group_cols)["initialtime"].agg([max, min]).eval('max-min').reset_index(name="journey_time")

speed = df.groupby(group_cols)["speed"].mean().reset_index(name="average_speed")

pd.merge(time, speed, on=group_cols)

         id journey_time  average_speed
0   car_duo     00:00:00           70.0
1  car_trio     00:12:00           77.5
2   car_uno     00:07:00           77.5
```

Comment: Area is important - in general above will work as car is usually at only two points, but it's about specifically when it is between those two points

Comment: In this case, it's a simple matter of adding `area` to groupby. Your sample data only has a handful of rows so the aggregated result will be the same as the original.

Comment: Thanks - Last point is, car could also be in separate part of the city, so may go through multiple places, so aggregation has to be somewhat time based

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what is it you're after. Happy to help further, but can you please include more sample code and your full expected output, not just output headers.

Answer (score 1):

I tryed to use a very intuitive solution. I'm assuming the data has already been loaded to `df`.

```
df['initialtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['initialtime'])

result = []

for car in df['id'].unique():
    _df = df[df['id'] == car].sort_values('initialtime', ascending=True)

    #  Where the car is leaving "from" and where it's heading "to"
    _df['From'] = _df['location']
    _df['To'] = _df['location'].shift(-1, fill_value=_df['location'].iloc[0])

   #  Auxiliary columns
    _df['end_time'] = _df['initialtime'].shift(-1, fill_value=_df['initialtime'].iloc[0])
    _df['end_speed'] = _df['speed'].shift(-1, fill_value=_df['speed'].iloc[0])
   
    #  Desired columns
    _df['journey_time'] = _df['end_time'] - _df['initialtime']
    _df['avg_speed'] = (_df['speed'] + _df['end_speed']) / 2

    _df = _df[_df['journey_time'] >= pd.Timedelta(0)]
    _df.drop(['location', 'distance', 'speed', 'end_time', 'end_speed'], 
             axis=1, inplace=True)

    result.append(_df)

final_df = pd.concat(result).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final DataFrame is as follows:

```
                       initialtime        id  From  To    journey_time  avg_speed
0 2020-09-18 12:03:14.485952+00:00   car_uno     1   2 0 days 00:07:00       77.5
1 2020-09-18 11:59:14.484781+00:00   car_duo     3   3 0 days 00:00:00       70.0
2 2020-09-18 12:00:14.484653+00:00  car_trio     7   8 0 days 00:12:00       77.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach.  My results are different that other posts, so I may have misunderstood the requirements.  In brief, I calculated each average speed as total distance divided by total time (for each car).

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# speed in km / hour; distance in km
data = '''location    initial-time id  speed distance
1   2020-09-18T12:03:14.485952Z car_uno 72 9
2   2020-09-18T12:10:14.485952Z car_uno 83 8
3   2020-09-18T11:59:14.484781Z car_duo 70 9
7   2020-09-18T12:00:14.484653Z car_trio    85 8
8   2020-09-18T12:12:14.484653Z car_trio    70 7.5
'''
```

Now create data frame and perform calculations

```
# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
df['elapsed-time'] = df['distance'] / df['speed'] # in hours

# utility function
def hours_to_hms(elapsed):
    ''' Convert `elapsed` (in hours) to hh:mm:ss (round to nearest sec)'''
    h, m = divmod(elapsed, 1)
    m *= 60
    _, s = divmod(m, 1)
    s *= 60
    hms = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(int(h), int(m), int(round(s, 0)))
    return hms

# perform calculations
start_time = df.groupby('id')['initial-time'].min()
journey_hrs = df.groupby('id')['elapsed-time'].sum().rename('elapsed-hrs')
hms = journey_hrs.apply(lambda x: hours_to_hms(x)).rename('hh:mm:ss')
ave_speed = ((df.groupby('id')['distance'].sum() 
             / df.groupby('id')['elapsed-time'].sum())
             .rename('ave speed (km/hr)')
             .round(2))

# assemble results
result = pd.concat([start_time, journey_hrs, hms, ave_speed], axis=1)

print(result)
                         initial-time  elapsed-hrs  hh:mm:ss  \
id                                                             
car_duo   2020-09-18T11:59:14.484781Z     0.128571  00:07:43   
car_trio  2020-09-18T12:00:14.484653Z     0.201261  00:12:05   
car_uno   2020-09-18T12:03:14.485952Z     0.221386  00:13:17   

          ave speed (km/hr)  
id                           
car_duo               70.00  
car_trio              77.01  
car_uno               76.79
```

Answer (score -3):

You should provide a better dataset (ie with identical time points) so that we understand better the inputs, and an exemple of expected output so that we understand the computation of the average speed.

Thus I'm just guessing that you may be looking for `df.groupby('initialtime')['speed'].mean()` if df is a dataframe containing your input data.

Comment: this should be a comment. you're not that far off from the 50 rep.